# fsmgmt.msc | stop process are running from specific directory | Remote server with invoke

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting, smb, network-share

I want to stop all the processes are running from specific directory if the process is from C:/CSV/X kill the process the server is remote but I have users are opened the files from different sessions so how can I kill it from different sessions

```
    $files = gci "C:\CSV\X\*"

foreach($file in $files){
    Get-Process | 
    Where-Object {$_.Path -eq $file.FullName} | 
    Stop-Process -Force -Verbose
}
```

I tried it and it doesn't work

For example we have a folder named: MyItem Inside the folder there is

MyItem/software.exe

MyItem/MyItem.exe

MyItem/MainMenu.exe

And I look for the processes through this: `fsmgmt.msc`

So I need to find a way to close all those whose source is MyItem/

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to terminate 'open files' accessed from the network you can do something like this:

```
#set path
$path = 'C:\CSV\X\'

#get smb open files in specified directory and close em, escape $path \ because of -match operator (regex)
Get-SmbOpenFile | ?{$_.path -match ($path -replace '\\','\\')} | Close-SmbOpenFile
```

No need to kill processes.

Comment: Good to know about [`Close-SmbOpenFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/close-smbopenfile). Killing processes would have have been a challenge anyway, as it would have to happen on all _clients_ connected to the server; however, it's worth noting that even though no client processes are _killed_, they are likely to become  unstable and/or lose data.

Comment: It may be better to use `? {` / `% {` rather than `?{` / `%{`, because the former makes it clear that `?` / `%` and `{` are distinct syntax elements: a cmdlet name (`?` / `%` are aliases of [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) / [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)), and `{`, the start of a [script block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) passed as an _argument_ to the cmdlet.

Comment: I don't think the solution you suggested is related at all, I just want to close open files that originate from a specific folder

Comment: yes, thats is what he code does.... you get all open files and filter for the specified path and close those